# How many forms can a Japanese verb take?

Tags: verbs, conjugations

Japanese verbs are quite complex compared to English verbs (Most English verbs have five or six forms and *to be* has eight not including archaic forms). Their agglutinative nature means they have various parts which can be present or not, or can take different morphemes.

What I'm wondering is if it is possible to calculate the total number of possible forms this can lead to for a typical Japanese verb.

If it's not straightforward or generally talked about, a reference to a discussion or research paper would also be a great answer.

Comment: But it's _precisely_ because it's agglutinative that the "number" of forms matters less! In my view, a Japanese verb has about six to ten "base" forms from which all other forms can be derived by regular rules.

Comment: In my view, there is one form.

Comment: @ZhenLin: For you it might not matter. For somebody writing software for a morphological analyser, a conjugator, or writing a book such as "501 Japanese verbs in every conjugation" it can matter a lot. In my case it's just an interesting factoid since I have seen people work out how many forms a verb can take in other morphologically complex languages such as Georgian and Arabic.

Comment: @sawa: Can you please explain? Are you saying that Japanese verbs don't inflect to make different forms but instead only come in one root form and are followed by other small words to create past, negative, differing politeness, etc??

Comment: @hippietrail I am saying that there is a root that is invariant, to which various affixes such as past, negation, politeness, etc. attaches.

Comment: @sawa: Hmm if you wouldn't use the term "verb form" to describe the result of adding a grammatical combination of such affixes to such an invariant verb root, which term would you suggest?

Comment: @sawa: Care to post an answer?  I would like to learn more about this modern view of conjugation in Japanese.  Also, is there a good book explaining this view in either Japanese or English so that I can learn more?

Comment: @hippietrail I use the term verb form informally to describe the result. Here, I did not because under that sense, it does not make sense to count.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I don't have anything more to say about it than the my comment above. A few pages in Shibatani *The Languages of Japan* mention the difference between traditional grammar and American structuralist view. But American structuralists such as Bloch or Martin still use the term "verb form" to describe many forms, but you can get the idea of a single invariant stem.

Comment: @sawa: Thank you for the pointer.  I will try to get that book.  Hope that I can borrow it from a nearby library. :)  As for posting an answer, I was hoping for comparison between different views on verb forms such as the one which aoeuueoa posted.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto And a book by Timothy Vance *An Introduction to Japanese Phonology* also discusses the difference between the traditional analysis and the American Structuralist view on verb inflection, and is actually in more detail than Shibatani's book. My point of view actually goes beyond the American structuralist's view, and belongs to what is called Distributed Morphology. This view is still under development, and there is no introductory book. All the relevant researches are on academic journals. When I have time, I my post relevant things sometimes.

Comment: @sawa: Thanks for another pointer and a keyword.  Seems like you should write a book about it. :)

Comment: I proceeded to ask the same thing on linguistics.SE the following day: [What is the maximum number of forms a (modern) Japanese verb can take?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2319)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on how you count. There are ~10 base forms to which you can append auxiliaries in a fairly regular manner. For reference, the handbook of Japanese verbs covers 154 conjugations which stem from ten different forms:

1. Conjunctive form (14)
2. Dictionary form (39)
3. Negative form (33)
4. Conditional form (5)
5. Imperative form (2)
6. Volitional form (5)
7. Te form (26)
8. Ta form (25)
9. Tara form (3)
10. Tari form (2)

But there is a lot of similarity among those, and there are probably both more and less inclusive lists.

Comment: I would actually be quite interested to see an exhaustive list. Does anyone know of one?

Comment: This seems to apply that in Japanese there are no restrictions on which auxiliaries or affixes can be used together, which would be surprising when compared to other languages with agglutinative verb morphology such as Georgian.

Comment: If one counts compound suffixes like 食べさせられる, then the total count is possibly infinite (I could do 食べさせられさせられさせられ...; even though it's meaningless it's still a grammatically valid conjugation).